# How do I remove the drop shadow on a VF Page embedded on a page layout?

Tags: visualforce-component, inline-visualforce

Some of my page layouts have VF pages embedded in them (for wrapping a VF component).  On the Account page layout they don't have boxes or drop shadows, but on my custom object, they do.  How can I "unbox" them and remove the drop shadow.

Images 1 and 2 are from Account with no container box/shadow.  Image 3 is from my custom object with box and shadow.

[image: Image 1 - Account inline VF, no box]

[image: Image 2 - Account inline VF, no box]

[image: Image 3 - Custom object inline VF, box and shadow]

Comment: are using page block in image 3?

Comment: No, just a very lightweight page to host the component.  The component itself is just the same hierarchy control as image 2, just with a different (custom) object.